# Divide and Conquer Algorithm using Multithreading

Tags: c, multithreading, algorithm, operating-system, pthreads

I am working on applying multi-threading on the divide and conquer algorithm so that I create a new thread each time the recursive function is called.
Here is the code of the algorithm alone(Works perfect):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int MAX_VALUE(int ARRAY[],int LEFT,int RIGHT)
{
    int MID;
    if(LEFT == RIGHT) return ARRAY[LEFT];
    else
    {
        MID = (LEFT + RIGHT) / 2;
        int U = MAX_VALUE(ARRAY, LEFT, MID);
        int V = MAX_VALUE(ARRAY, MID + 1, RIGHT);
        return (U > V ? U : V);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int N,i;

    printf("Enter the number of elements : ");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    int BUFFER[N];

    printf("Enter Array values : ");
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
        scanf("%d", &BUFFER[i]);

    printf("Maximum element in Array = %d", MAX_VALUE(BUFFER, 0, N-1));
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the above code combined with multi-threading(ERROR AT pthread_create: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

pthread_t THREAD_ID[5];

static int i = 0;
static int FLAG_FUNCTION_CALLS = 0;
static int FLAG_THREAD_ID = 0;

void *MAX_VALUE(int ARRAY[],int LEFT,int RIGHT)
{
    int ERR;
    FLAG_FUNCTION_CALLS++;

    int ACTIVE_THREAD_ID = pthread_self();

    int MID;
    if(LEFT == RIGHT)
    {
        if(FLAG_THREAD_ID <= 4)
        {
            printf("THREAD[%d] roger that and moving out...",ACTIVE_THREAD_ID);
            pthread_exit(&ARRAY[LEFT]);
        }
        else
        {
            return (void *) ARRAY[LEFT];
        }

    }
    else
    {
        MID = (LEFT + RIGHT) / 2;

        void *U;
        while(FLAG_FUNCTION_CALLS <= 4)
        {
            FLAG_THREAD_ID++;
            ERR = pthread_create(&(THREAD_ID[FLAG_THREAD_ID]), NULL, &MAX_VALUE(ARRAY, LEFT, MID), NULL);
            if (ERR != 0)
                fprintf(stderr, "\nFAILED CREATE THREAD!");
            else
                printf("\n Thread created successfully\n");
        }
        pthread_join(&THREAD_ID[FLAG_THREAD_ID],&U);

        void *V;
        while(FLAG_FUNCTION_CALLS <= 4)
        {
            FLAG_THREAD_ID++;
            ERR = pthread_create(&(THREAD_ID[FLAG_THREAD_ID]), NULL, &MAX_VALUE(ARRAY, MID + 1, RIGHT), NULL);
            if (ERR != 0)
                fprintf(stderr, "\nFAILED CREATE THREAD!");
            else
                printf("\n Thread created successfully\n");
        }
        pthread_join(&THREAD_ID[FLAG_THREAD_ID],&V);

        if(FLAG_THREAD_ID <= 4)
        {
            printf("THREAD[%d] roger that and moving out...",ACTIVE_THREAD_ID);
            pthread_exit(U > V ? &U : &V);
        }
        else
        {
            return (U > V ? (void *)U : (void *)V);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int N,i,ERR;
    void *MAXIMUM_VALUE;

    printf("\nEnter the number of elements : \n");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    int BUFFER[N];

    printf("\nEnter Array values : \n");
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
        scanf("%d", &BUFFER[i]);

    ERR = pthread_create(&(THREAD_ID[0]), NULL, &MAX_VALUE(BUFFER, 0, N-1), NULL);
    if (ERR != 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "\nFAILED CREATE THREAD!");
    else
        printf("\n Thread created successfully\n");

    pthread_join(&THREAD_ID[4],&MAXIMUM_VALUE);
    printf("\n%d\nNumber of time the recursive function is called: %d", (int)MAXIMUM_VALUE,FLAG_FUNCTION_CALLS);

    return 0;
}
```

I also wanted to create just 5 threads and each one will terminate and a new one is created after each function call, then only the 5th thread will continue executing and will return the final maximum value to the main function.

I am new to Operating System in C stuff if anyone could help that would be great. Thank you.

Comment: The prototype is `int pthread_create(pthread_t *, const pthread_attr_t *, void *(*) (void *), void *);`. The last argument of `pthread_create()` (`the void *`-argument)  is passed to the function the new thread starts in. You will have to modify your function to receive a pointer to a `struct` that contains the relevant members your function requires.

Comment: I do not code for linux but in windows the thread function must have also OS calling API specified like: `unsigned long __stdcall thread_function(LPVOID p);` where `p` is `far void*` passed from the Create thread function. If you want to pass anything else you need to overtype it to and from `void*`
`

Comment: Okay now I try to followed your tips so I came up with this : http://pastebin.com/qbRCVB5A
Still I got an ERROR line 27:assignment to expression with array type ..